# How can I access a TextView in my MainActivity from a class?

Tags: java, android, class, textview

I am trying to set a drawableLeft in a TextView in my MainActivity from my class.
How do I do this?

Thanks,

Vincent.

Comment: Please update your question with some code snippets of your XML. This seems to be a very basic question though. try using the findViewByID method in your activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kumar mentions above, most likely all you'll need to do is something like this (within your MainActivity).

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_id);
Textview tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
tv.setCompoundDrawables(d, null, null, null);
```

Again, this should be done within your Activity, since the findViewById() and the getResources() methods are available through the activity. If you're trying to do this type of thing from another class, make sure to pass the activity instance to the other class, and call these methods using that activity object.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the TextView to the class in the constructor.

Comment: Ah ya I meant to put the Activity Context - sorry.